# Can I use okta token for Microsoft Graph calendar event import api?

Tags: office365api

I am preparing an app where i need to import calendar events of users in the app. App already has okta authentication and my domain is configured with Office365 to use Okta.

Please advise if I can directly pass Okta token generated by my app to microsoft graph api and fetch calendar events of that user instead of registering an app of MicroSoft azure and using the client id of that app to generate token and use it further fot making calls to
Microsoft Graph calendar API.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you find solution for that ?